# Detect a frozen feed in Cosm

Tags: python, cosm

Using Cosm Data Logging.

Is it possible to create a trigger that sends an alert when a feed becomes frozen (i.e., data stops being received for over 15 minutes).

This would alert me when my wireless sensor network stops working.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 2):

You can create such triggers on your datastreams, either via the API or via the website.

See the [api docs for triggers](http://cosm.com/docs/v2/trigger/) or visit one of your feed pages on [cosm.com](https://cosm.com)